# How to zoom and scale WPF windows and Controls proportionately

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm developing a desktop app that will run on a 1080x1920 screen (an HD monitor in portrait mode). My development environment is a 1920x1080 screen (an HD laptop in landscape mode).

**I wanted to see the app in full screen locally, how do I go about?**

Tried setting the Window to the following resolution BUT the controls in it do not scale proportionately.

```
protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInitialized(e);
#if DEBUG
    this.Height = 960;
    this.Width = 540;

    this.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
#endif
}
```

My intention is to scale down both the window and the controls (in it) by half locally, so I would be able to debug locally on my laptop.

Comment: The simplest approach to proportional scaling would be to put your root grid in a viewbox. Set it's height and width.

Comment: @Andy your suggestion works. Thanks!